# when/how to free pointer returned from function

Tags: c, debugging, pointers, free

I have this function:

```
char * folderFromPath(char *path)
{
  printf("\nentered folderFromPath\n");

  char *token[80];
  int i = 0;  
  const int STR_LEN = 128;
  char str[STR_LEN];
  char *folder;
  folder = malloc(sizeof(path));
  strcpy(folder,"/");

  if (strlen(path) > STR_LEN)
  {
    printf("Warning: strlen(path) > STR_LEN, (%d > %d) in function folderFromPath\n", strlen(path), STR_LEN);
  }
  else
  {
      printf("path: %s\n", path);

    strcpy(str,path);

    token[0] = strtok(str, "/");

    while (token[i]!= NULL)
    {
      i++;
      token[i] = strtok (NULL, "/");
      printf("token[i]: %s, i: %d\n", token[i], i);
    }

    if (folder != NULL)
    {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < (i-1))
        {
              strcat(folder,token[j]);
              strcat(folder,"/");
            j++;
        }

        printf("folder: %s\n", folder);

    }

  } /* else if (strlen(path) < STR_LEN) */

  return folder;

}
```

In it you can see that I have dynamically allocated memory that is pointed to by `folder`.  You can also see that folder is returned to the calling function.  I saw [in this post](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/129372/how-to-free-pointers-which-are-to-be-returned) where it was suggested to free the pointer after it is used in the calling function.  So that is what I have done.  Here is the calling function:

```
void open_activated(GtkWidget *widget, GtkWindow *parent)
{
  GtkSourceLanguage *lang;
  GtkSourceLanguageManager *lm;
  GtkWidget *dialog;
  GtkWidget *tablabel;
  GtkTextBuffer *tbuffer;
  int openTabs = 0;
  char *folder1;
  const gchar *folder2;
  int page = 0;
  char *path;

  page = gtk_notebook_get_current_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook));
  path  = paths[notebookPages[page]];
  folder1 = folderFromPath(path);
  folder2 = folder1;

  dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Open File", parent, GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,GTK_STOCK_CANCEL,GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,GTK_STOCK_OPEN,GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,NULL);
  gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog), folder2);
  free(folder1); 

  tbuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(txtinput[openedPages]));

  gtk_source_buffer_begin_not_undoable_action(GTK_SOURCE_BUFFER(tbuffer));

  if(gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog))== GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
  {

    ...

  } /* if(gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog))== GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT) */

  gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
  changeLabelColor("black");
  gtk_text_buffer_set_modified (gtk_text_view_get_buffer((GTK_TEXT_VIEW(txtinput[openedPages]))), FALSE);

  gtk_source_buffer_end_not_undoable_action(GTK_SOURCE_BUFFER(tbuffer));
  write_config_files();

  verifyPaths();  

}
```

When I try to open a file, the application aborts and produces this statement:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./ledit: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x082a80c8 ***
```

So my question is what does this error mean and what should I do differently to properly free the pointer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is probably this.

```
char * folderFromPath(char *path)
...
folder = malloc(sizeof(path));
```

You are allocating `sizeof(path)`, which is the same as `sizeof(char*)`, since `path` is a `char*`. You're only allocating enough bytes to hold a single pointer, rather than the whole path which is probably what you intended.

Try instead:

```
folder = malloc(strlen(path)+1);
```

There may well be other problems; I haven't looked very closely. It does look as if you are correctly freeing the return `folder` after passing it to `gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder()`, although I don't know why you are assigning it to `folder2` as well. If you are expecting that assignment to copy the string (does the GTK function expect to take ownership of the path?) then you will be disappointed; you will have to take a separate copy of the string using `strncpy()` or something similar.

Comment: thank you that was it.  Now I am not having any crashes when opening files, where before I was having crashes all the time.  I'm learning. The reason I was assigning folder1 to folder2 was to cast it in the type expected by `gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder()`. It was a troubleshooting step that was a stretch, but I didn't know what else to try.  Now that I have made the change you suggested, I see that it is unnecessary.  Thanks again.